# IEnumerable.Count() O(n)

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I just stumbled upon this fragment of code, I was wondering why the Count is done during the loop.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// find the first index in a sequence to satisfy a condition
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">type of elements in source</typeparam>
  /// <param name="source">sequence of items</param>
  /// <param name="predicate">condition of item to find</param>
  /// <returns>the first index found, or -1 if not found</returns>
  public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate)
  {
         for (int i = 0; i < source.Count(); i++)
         {
               if (predicate(source.ElementAt(i))) return i;
         }
         return -1; // Not found
  }
```

If the count can change, shouldn’t we just do it like this instead: for (int i = source.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Otherwise, I think we should calculate the count before the looping starts, instead of every time.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct way to write manual code for this would be to lose all that rubbish and simply iterate with `foreach`:

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate) 
{
    var index = 0;
    foreach(var item in source) {
        if(predicate(item)) {
            return index;
        }
        ++index;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is **really** bad code, potentially - it could be iterating everything O (n^2), since Count() **might** need to iterate (if it doesn't implement ICollection-of-T/IList-of-T to offer .Count, which is tested), and ElementAt(x) might need to iterate x items, since it might not have IList-of-T for the indexer. It might work ok for lists/arrays, but in the general case it offers terrible performance. The worst case is that it iterates all n items n times (for the Count()s), plus the telescoping/triangular series, giving another n(n+1)/2 increments (for the ElementAt()s).

Just use foreach. Or better, look for an existing IndexOf method.

Answer (score 1):

If your going to use LINQ, then why not do it all in LINQ? LINQ was designed to be especially easy to use in situations like this.

Comment: How would he use LINQ to accomplish this more cleanly than a `foreach`? `IEnumerable` does not necessarily have an order, so LINQ does not have any built in index-oriented functionality for `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I was going to offer a LINQ alternative, but in this case it gets clunky: you need to project into an "item + index" anon type with `Select`, then filter by predicate, then return the first match or -1 if there is none. Straight `foreach` is much cleaner and concise.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, it does; most of the projection and selection functions provide overloads that provide an "index" (just a counter as in Jon's example). That's not to say that's the *right* way to do it, but to say that LINQ is index-ignorant is incorrect.

Comment: The LINQ idea jumped in my head because I've been dealing with a bunch of FP lately. I'll admit that a `foreach` is more direct, and the LINQ gets a little clunky, but it's not that bad: `return source.Select((x, i) => new Tuple<T, int>(x, i)).Aggregate(-1, (acc, x) => acc == -1 && predicate(x.Item1) ? x.Item2 : acc);` (or any number of other ways to do the same thing)

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: Regarding it being not that bad... IMHO if you put both snippets side by side, the code will speak for itself.

Comment: @Jon: I totally agree - `foreach` is better to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an O(n) way of doing it with Linq:

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> pred)
{
    var foundItem = 
        items
            .Select( (i,index) => new {i,index} )
            .FirstOrDefault( x => pred(x.i));
    return foundItem == null ? -1 : foundItem.index;
}
```